# Convert row to column in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can someone help me to resolve the issue?

I have a column "x" in a table "test"

X will have only one row of data = 1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11 like this.

I want to convert the row into columns, delimiter will be ",".

I have 2 columns a, b

data like

a    b

1   2

3   4

5   6

7   8

9  10

and i would expect the result to be 1-2,3-4,5-6,7-8,9-10(means form coulms to row)

ow can i achive this?

Comment: you want to convert the value of column 'x' into rows

Comment: post the sample data and desired result as its not clear that you want to split the column 'x' or want to concatenate it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is not clear whether you want to split the column or concatenate it so here i am providing you with both solutions:-

For splitting a string in oracle having delimiters ',' use below query:-

```
select DISTINCT to_number(regexp_substr(X,'[^,]+',1,level)) numbers 
from your_table
connect by to_number(regexp_substr(X,'[^,]+',1,level)) is not null
order by 1;
```

For concatenating a values of a column in oracle having multiple rows 
    with delimiters ',' use below query:-

```
select wm_concat(X) as column_x from your_table ;
```

Here is the complete demo code for your question and the solution query will give desired result  ...

```
create table dumdd   
(seq_id number,value varchar2(50))

insert all 
into dumdd values(1,'1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11')
into dumdd values(2,'1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11')
into dumdd values(3,'1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11')
select * from dual;

commit;

select seq_id,numbers from 
(
   select distinct seq_id,to_number(regexp_substr(value,'[^,]+',1,level)) numbers 
   from dumdd
connect by to_number(regexp_substr(value,'[^,]+',1,level)) is not null
)
where seq_id=1
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: there is not clear information to suggest it should be only numbers

Comment: @psaraj12 i assumed it as per question if its in case string then one remove to_number function while using it ..

Comment: Thanku.i would prefer first option(split string having delimiter ',' in oracle).i have sequence_no column in my table. for the given data sequence_no=1.so when i run your qury the result must affect only 8 rows but it's affecting 10 rows as it is taking next rows as well.

Comment: @user3195273 can you post the sample data with desired result ... which will help every one on SO to provide you with most appropriate answer..

Comment: Sample data (row1) x = 1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11 sequence_no =1 , x(row2) =1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11 sequence_no=2, x(row3)=1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11 sequence_no=3. Expected result : Depends on sequence_no provided row should be converted to columns(only for the given sequence_no). I hope this is clear now.

Comment: @user3195273 i  have posted the full demo code in this you will get your desired result .. try it

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below

```
select distinct regexp_substr(x,'[^,]+',1,level) from table
connect by level <=regexp_count(x,',')+1;
```

Comment: Just to bring in the notice for the people who are using oracle 10g and lesser version, one can use regexp_count() function on oracle version above 10g  ...And also the solution is absolutely right

Comment: Make a mention of this 10g and lesser restriction while answering to make it clear

Comment: Dear @psaraj12 this is just to prevent downvote (for such a useful answer) from the people who are seeking solution in  10g or lesser version and they are not aware of regexp_count() function ..

Comment: i agree without mentioning it in your answer how would they benefict